# C# WatiN cannot capture webpage to file

Tags: c#, watin

i'm getting error message when trying to capture web page. On my computer it works well but at my work it doesn't. Here is error http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/717/asdasfrfdf.jpg/ 
I'm using common code browser.CaptureWebPageToFile(address).
 Can anybody give me some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Please copy the error text directly into the question. The image might not last as long as the question, reading the error from that restricted viewport is only a partial message and, well, more tedious.

Comment: Cannot catch message.After i press "dont send report" button it throws me this exception. That screen capture is the only thing i cook take. Don't have Visual Studio here. Cannot debug.

Comment: It creates me .png file but it's empty. And my program stops right after that. I have browser.CaptureWebPageToFile(address) followed by console.writeline and text doesnt appear. So the problem is in capturing image and i wonder why

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while back.  Give this a go: -

```
using WatiN.Core.UtilityClasses;
...
string fName = @"C:\test.jpg";
using (FileStream fStr = new FileStream(fName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    CaptureWebPage cwp = new CaptureWebPage(browser.DomContainer);
    cwp.CaptureWebPageToFile(fStr, CaptureWebPage.ImageCodecs.Jpeg, true, false, 100, 100);
    fStr.Close();
}
```